# What did the non-standard html <comment> tag do?

Tags: html, internet-explorer

So I was reading [a blog](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html) that mentioned

> IE8 and below also support the (non-standard) `<comment>` tag.
>
> ```html
> This is <comment>not</comment> IE.
> ```

What is the `<comment>` tag supposed to do? I've tried searching for things like "html comment tag" but all I get is information about about the `<!-- -->` syntax.

Comment: Searching for `html "comment element"` (with the quotes, and "element" instead of "tag") turns up far more relevant results.

Comment: @BoltClock The google-fu is strong with this one. Thanks, I'll keep it in mind in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell it was functionally similar to `<!-- -->` comments in that text contained within it was hidden from the browser (in this case, IE). According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535229.aspx):

> The COMMENT element is treated as a no-scope element and does not expose any children.

The key difference is that the `<comment>` element supported a [`data` attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533702.aspx) pointing to a URL, supposedly with information that was related to the comment text, not unlike the `cite` attribute of `<blockquote>` and `<q>` that points to the source of a quotation. In HTML, `<!-- -->` comments don't have any built-in metadata whatsoever; they are nothing more than arbitrary strings that are ignored by the parser.

Answer (score 2):

This [2002 Usenet thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!search/$2B%22comment$20element%22$20/comp.infosystems.www.authoring.html/Zeuf1HtAgRk/f6j0hpDAsj4J) provides a nice discussion of the comment element's history.  Most relevant:

> Oh, how quickly they forget. The COMMENT element was created by...
>   Tim Berners-Lee. Or mabye Dan Connolly. The point is, it existed in
>   an early version of HTML (back before they were making formal DTDs),
>   and was quietly dropped when the W3C crew realized the COMMENT
>   element was bad SGML.

The closest to an "official word" can be found in the [1993 version](https://www.w3.org/MarkUp/draft-ietf-iiir-html-01.txt) of what we now call the HTML standard:

> Status: Obsolete
>
> A comment element used for bracketing off unneed text and comment
>     has been introduced in some browsers but will be replaced by the
>     SGML command feature in new implementations.

Hope this helps...

-- Lance

Comment: Fascinating. I wonder if it stuck around in IE simply because they never got around to removing it...